# Demonstrating Density Using the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness, approximation-theory, dense-subspaces

In exploring the dense subsets of $C\left(I_n\right)$, I've been particularly focused on the application of a foundational result:

$\textbf{Stone-Weierstrass Theorem}$: This theorem posits that for any compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of continuous real-valued functions on this set, if $\mathcal{A}$ separates the points and includes constant functions, then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(K)$.

Our interest lies in the functions of the form:
$$
G(x)=\sum_{k=1}^M \beta_k \prod_{j=1}^{N_k} \varphi\left(w_{j k}^T x+\theta_{j k}\right) (1)
$$
where $w_{j k} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \beta_j, \theta_{j k} \in \mathbb{R}$, and $x \in I_n$, under the $\textbf{valid property}$ that $\textbf{they form a dense subset in $C\left(I_n\right)$}$ using a nonconstant activation function $\varphi$.

My approach for proving it depends on identifying the set $\mathcal{U}$, given by the finite sums of products of the specified type, as an algebra of real continuous functions on $I_n$ that satisfies the conditions of the theorem: separation of points and inclusion of constant functions.

Despite understanding the theorem's prerequisites, I'm seeking a more rigorous mathematical justification to firmly establish $\mathcal{U}$ 's adherence to these conditions, thus proving its density in $C\left(I_n\right)$. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or detailed mathematical rigor that could illuminate this process."

Comment: Fascinating application of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem! It seems pivotal to demonstrate how your set $\mathcal{V}$ can indeed form an algebra that meets the theorem's conditions. Have you considered leveraging the properties of your activation function $\varphi$ to show that $\mathcal{V}$ can approximate any continuous function by constructing specific examples or using known algebraic properties of functions within $C\left(I_n\right)$?

Comment: Do you know that the result is true, and are you looking for a proof? Or it may be that the result fails? That does not look like an algebra, in general.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the comment. I changed the claim to "valid property" to reduce the confusion among readers. And coming to your question, yes, the result is true, that's why I was looking for solid, rigorous proof of it.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Basically, I wanted to mention in the original post as a hint that we can consider the set $\mathcal{U}$ given by the finite sums of products of the type (1). Without proof, $\mathcal{U}$ is an algebra of real continuous functions on $I_n$.

Comment: Yes, on closer look I now realise that is an algebra. It is quite self-evident actually

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, Hornik et al. 1989 somehow generalize the desired claim I mentioned above. But my professor gave a slightly easier property, which also holds true with the hints I included.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Precisely! Do you have any particular thoughts or analyses about how to complete the proof of this property more rigorously? We tried to solve this during the class but no particular correct approach was yielded at the end, especially with the hint I provided in the comments. It would be appreciated if you have any answers on this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to prove that the family
$$\tag{*}
\left\{\sum_{k=1}^M \beta_k \prod_{j=1}^{N_k} \varphi(w_{jk}^T x+\theta_{jk})\ :\ \beta_k, \theta_{jk}\in\mathbb R, w_{jk}\in\mathbb R^n\right\}$$
is an algebra. That is rather obvious for the following reason. Let me rename
$$\tag{$\dagger$}
f_{w_{jk}, \theta_{jk}}(x):=\varphi(w_{jk}^Tx+\theta_{jk}), $$
and to simplify notation, let me index it by just one parameter: $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$. This set $A$ consists of all $w_{jk}$ and all $\theta_{jk}$.

What is the smallest algebra containing all $f_\alpha$? For a set $\mathcal U$ to be an algebra, we need to be able to take linear combinations and pointwise products. So all elements of the form
$$\tag{**}
\sum_{k=1}^M \beta_k \prod_{j=1}^{N_k} f_{\alpha_{jk}}$$
must be in $\mathcal U$. Conversely, it is clear that the set consisting **precisely** of these elements is closed under linear combinations and pointwise products. We conclude that
$$
\mathcal{U}=\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^M \beta_k \prod_{j=1}^{N_k} f_{\alpha_{jk}}\ :\ M, N_k\in\mathbb N, \beta_k\in\mathbb R\right\}$$
is **the smallest algebra containing** $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$. Which means that our original (*) is the smallest algebra containing the functions of the form $(\dagger)$.

---

I hope this explains where does this set $(*)$ come from. Of course, it remains to prove that $(*)$ contains constants and separates points. The first condition is obvious, and correspond to $N_k=0$. The second depends on some specific property of $\varphi$. For example, the constant function $\varphi(x)=0$ violates it. I suppose that having a nonconstant $\varphi$ is enough to separate points, but that is for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to applying the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem through the lens of neural networklike functions is indeed intriguing. One aspect that might further illuminate your proof is considering the richness of the space generated by your function $G(x)$ under different choices of the activation function $\varphi$. Specifically, the role of $\varphi$ in ensuring the algebra $\mathcal{V}$ not only separates points but also universally approximates any function in $C\left(I_n\right)$ could be crucial. Have you explored how the specific properties of $\varphi$, such as smoothness or boundedness, impact the density of $\mathcal{V}$ within $C\left(I_n\right)$? This angle might reveal deeper connections between the algebraic structure of $\mathcal{V}$ and its approximation capabilities.

Comment: Might there be merit in examining the compactness of $I_n$ and how it influences the algebra $\mathcal{V}$ 's ability to approximate in $C\left(I_n\right)$? Wondering if alternative activation functions or extensions to $\mathcal{V}$ could offer new insights.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this answer, frankly. The only property of $\varphi$ that should enter the picture is that it never vanishes, which is also the only assumption furnished by the question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wrote "never vanishes", I meant "is not constant".